# SSAS Excel ignores row level filters

Tags: ssas, hierarchy

I have an SSAS cube, that is producing unexpected results in Excel.

The problem occurs when I place a hierarchy on the report filter and then place a member of the same hierarchy on the row labels.

Example:

The hierarchy is called `By Country`, it is part of the `Customer` dimension.  It contains three levels, `Country`, `District` and `CustomerId`.

```
By Country              Hierarchy
UK                      Level 1 - Country
    Essex               Level 2 - District
    Kent                "
    Hertfordshire       "
    West Sussex         "
    Suffolk             "
USA                     Level 1 - Country
    Montant             Level 2 - District 
    North Dakota        "
    Oklahoma            "
    Texas               "
```

I've not shown `CustomerId`, but this is a surrogate key.  A unique value is issued to each customer.

When I place `District` on the row labels, I receive the expected breakdown of sales.  However when I place `By Country` on the report filter, I lose the breakdown.  Next to each `district` the total sales value is shown.

[image]

This does not happen when I repeat the example in BIDS.

This is a SQL Server 2008 R2 OLAP cube, used via Excel 2010.

Can anyone spot what I am doing wrong?

Comment: There were a lot of bugs in Excel 2010 vs SSAS cubes - it got much better in the 2 major releases in the intervening 7 years.  I would certainly upgrade and retest.